# Facebook album Query and graph api returns empty set

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I have written a code to get all album names to list it. When i write code using javascript 
it returned me an empty set.

```
FB.api('/me/albums', function(response) {

});
```

I tried Query also . It also returned me an empty set

```
SELECT aid,owner,name FROM album WHERE owner = me().
```

I am having album in my account but still it is returning empty set. Please help me in figuring out

Comment: As per the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/), do you have the `user_photos` permission?

Answer (score 0):

include access_token in parameters list

```
 FB.api('/me/albums?access_token=' + accessToken, function(response) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user has authorized the app and supply the access token with the query;

```
FB.api('/me/albums?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN', function(response) 
{
    console.log(response);

});
```